# iSCSI LUN from Centos mapped to xenserver is keep on disappearing

Tags: centos7, iscsi, xenserver, targetcli

I'm trying to set up an ISCSI box for shared storage to connect to my xenserver environment. I am using Centos 7 as iSCSI storage. I am using targetcli for iSCSI configuration.

I can set up everything just fine, the xenserver machine will connect and format the volume. I can set up VMS on it and all works fine until I reboot.

At this point the xenserver box will no longer connect and mapped LUN is shown as disconnected. Looking at the storage box a little further, I see that the LUN is not there anymore. But when I run "gdisk /dev/sda"; I do see the partition. Its only not visible in targetcli anymore. If I try to re-attach/create the LUN in targetcli then it tells me that the disk is in use.

/backstores/block> create xenhq_vl01 /dev/sda5
Cannot configure StorageObject because device /dev/sda5 is already in use

There is one another LUN mapped to a windows box which is not part of xen and it is working perfectly alright.

Below image is taken right after the LUN got disappeared. I also tried to re-create the same LUN but it gave an error.

[Output of targetcli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evj77.png)

After rebooting the Xen box; messages file in Centos reported following:

Jun 27 07:27:44 STGHQ01 target: Could not create StorageObject xenhq_vl01: Cannot configure StorageObject because device /dev/sda5 is already in use, skipped

Jun 27 07:27:44 STGHQ01 target: Could not find matching StorageObject for LUN 0, skipped

Jun 27 07:27:44 STGHQ01 target: Could not find matching TPG LUN 0 for MappedLUN 0, skipped

Any recommendations/suggestions? What am I missing here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I even tried using filters and global filters in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf but nothing worked out. So instead of using 'block' device; I ended up using "fileio" in targetcli. Everything works perfectly alright now.